# Can artists feature art that they've sold in their portfolio?

Tags: copyright, legal, portfolio, art

Is it okay for me to have artwork that has already been sold in my portfolio? Or does all of the work I put in my portfolio need to be for sale?

Comment: Portfolios aren't generally sales vehicles.

Comment: How do you define "portfolio"? Also, do you have any terms of sale that artwork was sold using?